# ElasticSearch - How to aggregation access log ignore GET parameter?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to aggregate access by function path.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "path.keyword": "/hex/*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "path": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "path.keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And i get the result like these..

```
{
  "key": "/hex/user/admin_user/auth",
  "doc_count": 38
},
{
  "key": "/hex/report/chart/fastreport_lobby_all?start_date=2017-06-29&end_date=2017-07-05&category=date_range&value[]=payoff",
  "doc_count": 35
},
{
  "key": "/hex/report/chart/fastreport_lobby_all?start_date=2017-06-29&end_date=2017-07-05&category=lobby&value[]=payoff",
  "doc_count": 35
},
{
  "key": "/hex/report/chart/online_membership?start_date=2017-06-29&end_date=2017-07-05&category=datetime_range&value[]=user_total",
  "doc_count": 34
}
```

There are two /hex/report/chart/fastreport_lobby_all?balabala... result.

It's not the real count about this function.

Do i have any method to count these as one?

```
{
  "key": "/hex/report/chart/fastreport_lobby_all",
  "doc_count": 70
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without a custom analyzer like

```
PUT your_index
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "query_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "split_query",
               "filter": ["top1"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "top1":{
                     "type": "limit",
                     "max_token_count": 1
                  }
         },
         "tokenizer":{
             "split_query":{
                  "type": "pattern",
                  "pattern": "\\?"
               }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "your_log_type": {
         "properties": {
            "path": {
               "type": "text",
               "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                      "type":"keyword"
                  },
                  "no_query": {
                      "type":"string",
                      "fielddata":true,
                      "analyzer":"query_analyzer"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And then query on

```
POST test/log_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "path.keyword": "/hex/*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "aggs" : {
        "genres" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "path.no_query" }
        }
    }
}
```